# Azure Search | Why is the lowest interval to re-run the index set to 5 minutes?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm working on pulling files via azure search in C#.

I have everything set up, but if I upload a new file, it takes 5 minutes for the file to be indexed to show up in the list of upload files after I pass in a specific filter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-schedule-indexers

Is there anyway around this?

Is there a way to run the indexer immediately after upload?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine Event Grid / Azure functions with Blob Storage Binding to trigger your indexer.

Run indexer REST API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/run-indexer

```
[FunctionName("BlobTriggerCSharp")]        
public static void Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}")] Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
    //call the indexer from previous link
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp